# Doubt on zero dimensional space

Tags: coordinate-systems

Consider the case of two lines that do not intersect at any point on the 2-D plane. Is it correct to say that the intersection of the two lines belongs to the zero dimensional space or is my question absurd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero-dimensional (sub-)space is $\{0\}$, so no, that's incorrect to say.

Comment: I agree that in a formal sense a point is not a subspace, But we do say often that a line is a 1-D space (not meaning it as a vector space), and in the same way perhaps one could say that a point is a 0-dimensional space.

Comment: @gt6989b: One might certainly think of a singleton as a $0$-dimensional affine subspace, but the empty set is not a singleton.

Comment: @CameronBuie you are right, i misread the question, thought the lines intersected somehow. Sorry, thanks.